# How to represent hierarchical data in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following tree that I need to represent in JSON. This is a response to an HTTP request and put together on the server done in Java.

```
San Diego
    Hospital
       number1
       number2
LA
    LA hospital

SF
    clinic
       The best one
```

How Do i represent this is JSON?
I have attempted a lot of variations and my difficulty is how to define the keys for lists that I only have names (values) for.

Comment: Can we have code you used for ajax request?

Comment: are these in arrays or objects? it really depends on a lot of missing details...

Comment: what have you tried, please attempt to put the data in JSON and then we will help you get the formatting right.  you need to show what you have tried.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify() ..

Comment: Updated the original question. The request is a get : http://IP/locations

Comment: @reza Your update still doesn't really explain what your desired output is or even what the structured input is from the server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll bite...

```
var cities = [{Name: "San Diego", Hospitals: ["Hospital number1", "Hospital number2"]},
{Name: "LA", Hospitals: ["LA Hospital"]},
{Name: "SF", Hospitals: ["clinic The best one"]}];
```

This simply represents a dictionary of a string->string-array pair.

Just one interpretation of the "data structure" you provided. Really, we need more details in order to help you.

Comment: may be the updated question helps to show what part I am struggling with, which is what to use for keys for a list of values. Does that make any sense? Actually I think your answer IS what I needed.